# Streaming data Complex Event Processing over files and a rather long period

Tags: streaming, complex-event-processing

my challenge:

- we receive files every day with about 200.000 records. We keep the files for approx 1 year, to support re-processing, etc..
- For the sake of the discussion assume it is some sort of long lasting fulfilment process, with a provisioning-ID that correlates records.
- we need to identify flexible patterns in these files, and trigger events
- typical questions are:

  - if record A is followed by record B which is followed by record C, and all records occured within 60 days, then trigger an event
  - if record D or record E was found, but record F did NOT follow within 30 days, then trigger an event
  - if both records D and record E were found (irrespective of the order), followed by ... within 24 hours, then trigger an event
- some pattern require lookups in a DB/NoSql or joins for additional information either to select the record, or to put into the event.
- "Selecting a record" can be simple "field-A equals", but can also be "field-A in []" or "filed-A match " or "func identify(field-A, field-B)"
- "days" might also be "hours" or "in previous month". Hence more flexible then just "days". Usually we have some date/timestamp in the record.  The maximum is currently "within 6 months" (cancel within setup phase)
- The created events (preferably JSON) needs to contain data from all records which were part of the selection process.
- We need an approach that allows to flexibly change (add, modify, delete) the pattern, optionally re-processing the input files.

Any thoughts on how to tackle the problem elegantly?  May be some python or java framework, or does any of the public cloud solutions (AWS, GCP, Azure) address the problem space especially well?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

After some discussions and readings, we'll try first Apache Flink with the FlinkCEP library. From the docs and blog entries it seems to be able to do the job. It also seems AWS's choice, running on their EMR cluster.  We didn't find any managed service on GCP nor Azure providing the functionalities. Of course we can always deploy and manage it ourselves. Unfortunately we didn't find a Python framework

Comment: I suggest you also take a look at Flink's SQL engine, which supports the MATCH_RECOGNIZE standard for pattern recognition (including a non-standard WITHIN clause for time constraints). See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/match_recognize.html.